# What do Green and Copy mean in CD-INFO?

Tags: audio, burning, audio-cd

I am trying to burn an Audio CD to be playable on old vintage CD Players. 
I have tried using Brasero Audio CD and XfBurner, to no avail. 
The resulting CD is playable only on some newer players.

I have a CD (that I got from someone) which works. 
So I analyzed it using `cd-info`.

**This is the information about the working CD:**

```
Disc mode is listed as: CD-DA
CD-ROM Track List (1 - 20)
  #: MSF       LSN    Type   Green? Copy? Channels Premphasis?
  1: 00:02:00  000000 audio  false  no    2        no
  2: 01:43:04  007579 audio  false  no    2        no
  3: 03:30:68  015668 audio  false  no    2        no
  4: 05:45:37  025762 audio  false  no    2        no
  5: 07:33:14  033839 audio  false  no    2        no
  6: 09:27:53  042428 audio  false  no    2        no
  7: 10:57:36  049161 audio  false  no    2        no
  8: 12:57:33  058158 audio  false  no    2        no
  9: 14:18:70  064270 audio  false  no    2        no
 10: 16:02:30  072030 audio  false  no    2        no
 11: 17:36:57  079107 audio  false  no    2        no
 12: 18:59:35  085310 audio  false  no    2        no
 13: 21:08:00  094950 audio  false  no    2        no
 14: 22:11:08  099683 audio  false  no    2        no
 15: 23:32:35  105785 audio  false  no    2        no
 16: 25:52:23  116273 audio  false  no    2        no
 17: 27:00:12  121362 audio  false  no    2        no
 18: 29:55:43  134518 audio  false  no    2        no
 19: 31:39:27  142302 audio  false  no    2        no
 20: 33:10:26  149126 audio  false  no    2        no
170: 35:05:28  157753 leadout (353 MB raw, 353 MB formatted)
Media Catalog Number (MCN): 0000000000000
Last CD Session LSN: 0
audio status: no status
volume level port 0: 255 (0..255) 100 (0..100)
volume level port 1: 255 (0..255) 100 (0..100)
volume level port 2:   0 (0..255)   0 (0..100)
volume level port 3:   0 (0..255)   0 (0..100)
```

**And this is the information about my CD from Brasero
(it is the same for XfBurner):**

```
Disc mode is listed as: CD-DA
CD-ROM Track List (1 - 1)
  #: MSF       LSN    Type   Green? Copy? Channels Premphasis?
  1: 00:02:00  000000 audio  true   yes   2        no
170: 06:00:61  026911 leadout (60 MB raw, 60 MB formatted)
Media Catalog Number (MCN): 0000000000000
Last CD Session LSN: 0
audio status: no status
volume level port 0: 255 (0..255) 100 (0..100)
volume level port 1: 255 (0..255) 100 (0..100)
volume level port 2:   0 (0..255)   0 (0..100)
volume level port 3:   0 (0..255)   0 (0..100)
```

It seems the only differences are the `Green?` and `Copy?` fields. 
What is the meaning of these fields?

Any suggestions on writing compatible Digital Audio CDs for old players?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Green?` is a bit obscure, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/xbmc/libcdio/blob/master/src/cd-info.c#L1051) and then [`libcdio` programming documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/) helps: it seems to refer to whether or not the [track contains CD-ROM XA data](https://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/doxygen/track_8h.html#a6ed543e16c8fa8e21b83571f61e96084) and therefore is [CD-I (Green Book) compatible](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/cd-rom-xa).

> The original CD-ROM format is known as Mode 1, and XA is known as Mode 2. There are two sector formats in XA: Mode 2 Form 1 contains all the error correction as in Mode 1. **This mode is sometimes the default for CD-R authoring programs, because it provides more compatibility with multisession discs.**

So, for vintage CD players, you would want to burn the whole disc at once, without turning off the laser in the middle. In other words, select "single-session" and "disc-at-once" if your burner and software allows, or "single-session" and "session-at-once" if that's the best your system can do.

The first CD burners could only do "disc-at-once". Then multi-session technology was developed for CD-Rs and CD-RWs, and track-at-once burning became the default. Later, the "session-at-once" burning method was developed to be the multi-session equivalent of "disc-at-once", to improve compatibility with older CD players (among other reasons).

`Copy?` is the [copy protection status of the track](https://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/doxygen/track_8h.html#afd4db968d5cfd6b6af782e06a9ad7d7e). I think some old stand-alone CD players might refuse to output the audio in digital format when this is set to `no`, to prevent copying the track digitally to a DAT tape.

Comment: Simple link for other book colors / specs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Books